# Utilizar indexación IXSSO.Query en web ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, asp, migracion

Tengo que modificar una parte de una web que fue migrada de ASP clásico a ASP .Net, y en ella se usaba un ActiveX (ixsso.dll) con el que se hacían indexaciones de contenido de documentos, y luego se hacían consultas de lo indexado.

En la web ASP .Net, la llamada para instanciar no es posible:

```
Dim oQuery = Server.CreateObject("IXSSO.Query")
```

El mensaje que da es el siguiente:

> "No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {EAFDF8B3-3BE5-4E05-BF86-1E486B2FEF9D} debido al siguiente error: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

La dll "C:\windows\system32\ixsso.dll" está bien registrada (la he desregistrado y registrado de nuevo con regsvr32) y el proyecto está en modo depuración de x86 (para que esté en modo 32 bit).

¿Es posible hacer funcionar esta dll en .Net? ¿Hay que registrar algo más? ¿Alguna sugerencia?